# Unable to receive SNS messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I had SNS working but understood I couldn't attach larger files to my messages but learned I could with SES.  So I "connected" my SNS to SES using [Configuring Amazon SNS Notifications for Amazon SES - Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-sns-notifications.html) (I used the email address rather than domain).

After this configuration, I no longer received emails as I am in "Sandbox" mode. So, I deleted my email address from SES - nothing. I even deleted my email address from SNS topic and can't get any communication at all - even the "Request Confirmation" emails are not sent.  It is not my Outlook service as I tested other emails.

Any advice would be much appreciated. I just want to get back to where I was able to send SNS messages.

Comment: So, let's start from the basics... If you add your email address as a subscription on the Amazon SNS topic, do you receive a confirmation message? Can you try it with another email address (eg Gmail) to test?

Comment: Hi John!  thanks so much for replying :)  Yes, i sent to different gmail address and i got the confirmation email and am now confirmed....

Comment: I also created a new Topic and requested subscription confirmation to my primary email address and did not receive an email requesting confirmation.  Is it that my primary email address is locked or something like that?  thanks for your help and guidance...

Comment: I wonder if it involves [Removing an Email Address from the Amazon SES Suppression List - Amazon Simple Email Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/remove-from-suppression-list.html)?

Comment: hi again John :).  I removed the email address from the suppression list and still no email....few other possible clues: I tried to confirm the subscription and it prompted me to enter "Subscription confirmation URL".  I dont think I had to do that before the SES incident.  I wondered if I set it up for HTTP rather than email and decided to delete the email address from the Topic.  I received message that it was deleted but it still shows as "Pending Confirmation" in the list....ugh.